# Paste multiple data.table columns into single column based on unique values

Tags: r, string, data.table, paste

I have a data.table that looks like this:

```
require("data.table")

dt1 <- data.table(VAR1 = c("Brick","Sand","Concrete","Stone"), VAR2 = c(100,23,76,43), VAR3 = c("Place","Location","Place","Vista"), VAR4 = c("Place","Tree","Wood","Vista"), VAR5 = c("Place","Tree","Wood","Forest"))
```

I would like to paste named columns (my real data has additional columns) together in this order: VAR2, VAR1, VAR3, VAR4 and VAR5. However, I have two conditions:

- Values in the same row should not be duplicated (when values are duplicated the column with the last entry should be the one kept - so in my example 'Place' in VAR5 would be the one retained)
- A comma should be a separator when pasting except for between VAR2 and VAR1

My expected output would look like this:

```
dt2 <- data.table(VAR6 = c("100 Brick, Place","23 Sand, Location, Tree","76 Concrete, Place, Wood","43 Stone, Vista, Forest"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `do.call(paste` after selecting the column in the order in `.SDcols`, removve the duplicate words with a regex expression

```
dt1[,  .(VAR6 = sub(",", " ", gsub("\\b(\\w+)\\b\\s*,\\s*(?=.*\\1)", "", 
      do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep=",")), perl = TRUE))), 
           .SDcols = names(dt1)[c(2:1, 3:5)]]
#                     VAR6
#1:        100 Brick,Place
#2:  23 Sand,Location,Tree
#3: 76 Concrete,Place,Wood
#4:  43 Stone,Vista,Forest
```

---

or group by  the sequence of rows and do the `paste`

```
V6 <- dt1[, sprintf("%s %s, %s", VAR2, VAR1, 
   toString(unique(unlist(.SD)))), 1:nrow(dt1), .SDcols = VAR3:VAR5]$V1
data.table(V6)
#                     V6
#1:         100 Brick, Place
#2:  23 Sand, Location, Tree
#3: 76 Concrete, Place, Wood
#4:  43 Stone, Vista, Forest
```

Comment: Adapted your answer so I add VAR6 to existing dt1: dt1[,VAR6 := dt1[, sprintf("%s %s, %s", VAR2, VAR1, toString(unique(unlist(.SD)))), 1:nrow(dt1), .SDcols = VAR3:VAR5]$V1]

Comment: If I wanted a comma to separate all columns (including VAR2 and VAR1) what would need to change?

Comment: @Chris In that case, you just need to remove the `sub(",", " ",` and the closing `)`